# Is there any way to show the flags being used in a running JVM?

Tags: java, jvm

Although we've explicitly set a number of JVM flags for our applications, it's very difficult to know if:
1. Boolean flags are already on by default (defaults changed between minor JDK/JRE updates)
2. One flag negates the other
3. What the default value of a given arbitrary flag is on your specific systems (Set by Java ergonomics)

To sum up:
Is there a command line tool similar to

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal
```

, where I can check the all flag values for an already running JVM?

Answer (score 6):

For HotSpot you can use (From ehcache)

```
private static String getHotSpotVmOptionValue(String name) {
    try {
        MBeanServer server = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
        ObjectName beanName = ObjectName.getInstance("com.sun.management:type=HotSpotDiagnostic");
        Object vmOption = server.invoke(beanName, "getVMOption", new Object[] {name}, new String[] {"java.lang.String"});
        return (String)((CompositeData)vmOption).get("value");
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, I guess I'm hoping for a one-size-fits-all command line approach rather than looping through each option. But you've made me think about JMX, so perhaps something like http://wiki.cyclopsgroup.org/jmxterm might work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [jinfo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jinfo.html). It lets you both view and set JVM flags from the command line. It's one of many widely unknown [Tools and Utilities](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/) for the JVM.

Comment: Hey Ryan, I just tried jinfo. Unfortunately, it only lists the flags that the user has explicitly set. I'm interested in seeing the values of all user-set and jvm-set flags. That page is really useful though!

Answer (score 0):

This technique applies for any java application running local or remote.

1. Start your java application
2. Run [JVisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/) found in you JDK (such as C:\Program
   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\jvisualvm.exe)
3. When this useful tool starts look at the list of running java application under the
   "Local" tree node.
4. Double click [your application] (pid [n]) in the tree
5. On the right side there will be inspection contents in tab for the 
   application. In the middle of the Overview tab you will see the JVM
   arguments for the application.

jvisualvm can be found in any JDK since JDK 6 Update 7.  Video tutorial on jvisualvm is [here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z8n7Bg7-A4I)